# How can I use the normal radio buttons in react?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am developing a webapp which uses materializecss, react along with ruby on rails. I'd like to know how I can use the radio buttons such that it can be rendered.

```
    class Radio extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {

  }

  this.setNewNumber = this.setNewNumber.bind(this)
};

 setNewNumber(event) 
{
    this.setState({val : event.target.value})

}

render() {
  return (

     <div>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onChange={this.setNewNumber}/> Male<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"onChange={this.setNewNumber}/> Female<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"onChange={this.setNewNumber}/> Other
        <p>Enter {this.state.val}</p>
     </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: So that it can be rendered? I dont really understand what you are asking for

Comment: So, what happens when I execute this is the radio buttons are not even shown, so I cannot choose any option.

Comment: When you execute it? Do you have a global render, that makes sure that react renders within some part of your page? Typically react-dom.render